# why HTTP proxy can't be used?

Tags: server, apache2, proxy

My home internet connection is via pppoe, an Apache2 server is installed on VPS  114.114.114.114.

Contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` on VPS 114.114.114.114 .

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    <Proxy *>
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Mod proxy and proxy_http enabled on vps.
Now it is proxy setting on my local machine's Firefox.

[image]
To restart Firefox and test on my local pc's terminal.

```
curl -x 114.114.114.114:80  -I www.yahoo.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2016 03:20:12 GMT
Server: ATS
Via: https/1.1 ir25.fp.ir2.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer)
Location: https://www.yahoo.com/
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Content-Length: 304
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain
```

Why the via is not  114.114.114.114?

The HTTP request have not posted to my HTTP proxy  114.114.114.114, it posted directly from my localhost, how to post the HTTP request to my HTTP proxy 114.114.114.114?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is ok and `curl` results are also ok.

The `Via 1.1 localhost.localdomain` was added by your proxy at 104.224.147.201.

You need to change its hostname. You might also want to set `ProxyVia full` to confirm its operations.